# Katalon can't click object which exist

Tags: selenium, testing, katalon-studio, katalon

I use Katalon for web testing for some time and I have problem now:
I have Test Suite which uses many objects from Object Repository. My problematic object is called "Tabs - Adres" and it uses senchatest mark to detect clickable object on web app:

[image]

It looks fine and works fine but obly when I execute test from this level with RUN button:

[image]

The problem starts when I want to use my Test Suite, which contains above Test Case:

[image]

Then I had ERROR which concerns my 'Tab - Adres' object, but it do not have any sense, because Test Case has no problem with this Object:

```
=============== ROOT CAUSE =====================
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/Dzial - Nieruchomosci/Okno - Nieruchomosci/Tabs - Nieruchomosci/Tab - Adres' located by '//*[@senchatest='listingeditwindow_tab_address']' not found

Click here to fix broken Test Object
================================================

05-25-2021 12:23:55 PM click(findTestObject("Dzial - Nieruchomosci/Okno - Nieruchomosci/Tabs - Nieruchomosci/Tab - Adres"))

Elapsed time: 1m - 1,469s

Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Dzial - Nieruchomosci/Okno - Nieruchomosci/Tabs - Nieruchomosci/Tab - Adres' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Dzial - Nieruchomosci/Okno - Nieruchomosci/Tabs - Nieruchomosci/Tab - Adres'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.click(ClickKeyword.groovy:75)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.execute(ClickKeyword.groovy:42)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.click(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:619)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$click$6.call(Unknown Source)
    at Okno - nowa Nieruchomosc - Magazyn Sprzedaz - wypelnienie maksymalne.run(Okno - nowa Nieruchomosc - Magazyn Sprzedaz - wypelnienie maksymalne:54)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:398)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:389)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:368)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:360)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:255)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.doCall(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:59)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.call(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.callTestCase(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.execute(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:44)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.BuiltinKeywords.callTestCase(BuiltinKeywords.groovy:334)
    at Menu gorne - PLUS - Dodaj nowe Nieruchomosci - Magazyn sprzedaz.run(Menu gorne - PLUS - Dodaj nowe Nieruchomosci - Magazyn sprzedaz:31)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:398)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:389)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:368)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:360)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:255)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.doCall(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:59)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.call(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.callTestCase(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.execute(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:44)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.BuiltinKeywords.callTestCase(BuiltinKeywords.groovy:334)
    at Brute Force - Magazyn sprzedaz.run(Brute Force - Magazyn sprzedaz:18)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:398)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:389)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:368)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:360)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:255)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:203)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:152)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:95)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1621938043876.run(TempTestSuite1621938043876.groovy:39)
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/Dzial - Nieruchomosci/Okno - Nieruchomosci/Tabs - Nieruchomosci/Tab - Adres' located by '//*[@senchatest='listingeditwindow_tab_address']' not found
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.common.WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(WebUiCommonHelper.java:1368)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword.findWebElement(WebUIAbstractKeyword.groovy:27)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword.findWebElement(WebUIAbstractKeyword.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword$_click_closure1.doCall(ClickKeyword.groovy:66)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword$_click_closure1.call(ClickKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.click(ClickKeyword.groovy:75)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.execute(ClickKeyword.groovy:42)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.click(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:619)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$click$6.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1540554981354.run(Script1540554981354.groovy:54)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:398)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:389)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:368)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:360)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:255)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.doCall(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:59)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.call(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.callTestCase(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.execute(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:44)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.BuiltinKeywords.callTestCase(BuiltinKeywords.groovy:334)
    at Script1562673620600.run(Script1562673620600.groovy:31)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:398)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:389)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:368)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:360)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:255)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.doCall(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:59)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.call(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.callTestCase(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword.execute(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:44)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:73)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.BuiltinKeywords.callTestCase(BuiltinKeywords.groovy:334)
    at Script1562674449345.run(Script1562674449345.groovy:18)
    ... 13 more
)
```

Please help

Comment: Can you share the code you are running to produce this error?

Comment: Yes, you can fing below, it is line WebUI.click(findTestObject('Dzial - Nieruchomosci/Okno - Nieruchomosci/Tabs - Nieruchomosci/Tab - Adres'))